How can I extract a JavaScript from a PDF using pypdf?
I've successfully added a JavaScript to a PDF using writer.add_js(js_string) in pypdf. But I cannot figure out if there's a way to extract the JavaScript from a pdf using pypdf.
The script that I would like to extract from a PDF using pypdf looks like this in the PDF:
4 0 obj
<< /JavaScript
 << /Names
    [ (JSInit) << /Type /Action /S /JavaScript /JS (
function ShM\(aEntries\) {
    var aParams = [];
    for \(var i in aEntries\) {
        aParams.push\({
            cName: aEntries[i][0],
            cReturn: aEntries[i][1]
        }\)
    }

    var cChoice = app.popUpMenuEx.apply\(app, aParams\);
    if \(cChoice != null && cChoice.substring\(0, 1\) == '#'\) this.pageNum = parseInt\(cChoice.slice\(1\)\);
    else if \(cChoice != null && cChoice.substring\(0, 4\) == 'http'\) app.launchURL\(cChoice\);
}
) >> ]
 >>
>>
endobj

I want to extract this script from one file, and write it to another. The reason that I'd like to extract it is that it might change in the future.
Edit: I'm using pypdf 4.2.0

Try this method, it should work. Additionally, it may also capture false positives, extracting text that resembles JavaScript but isn't actually code
import PyPDF2
import re

def extract_javascript_from_pdf(pdf_file):
    
    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as file:
       
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        
       
        extracted_text = ""
        
        
        for page_num in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
            extracted_text += page.extractText()
        
        
        javascript_code = re.findall(r'<script.*?>(.*?)</script>', extracted_text, re.DOTALL)
        
        
        return javascript_code

pdf_file = "example.pdf"
javascript_code = extract_javascript_from_pdf(pdf_file)
for code in javascript_code:
    print(code)


Thank you!
I can try with PyPDF2 later today, but I made a quick test using pypdf 4.2.0 that wasn't successful.
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader(src)
page = reader.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())

This gives no output at all from my pdf. :(

Thanks for all your comments! I was really hoping that it was possible to do with pypdf in some way, but I'll do it by parsing the decompressed file for /JS instead.

Sure that sounds alright. I'm sorry that this approach din't really come out as any help
